# PHP $_FILE или Nginx module upload

Tags: nginx, php, upload

Привет!

Есть возможность закачки файлов на сервер 2 способами:

1. PHP `$_FILE[]`
2. Nginx module upload

С точки зрения эффективности и быстродействия при загрузке файлов на сервер какой вариант выбрать?

Учитывая что frontend - NGINX и backend Apache.

Comment: Из описания выдно юзаешь PHP то $_FILE.

Comment: Я пока ничего не юзаю. Я хочу выяснить более правильнее быдет делать это на уровне nginx или php. Больше склонюсь к nginx. Но хотелось бы услышать мнение профессионала, если возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx upload module будет эффективнее, поскольку тело POST запроса будет сразу же писаться во временный файл и на backend будет передан лишь путь к файлу. В то время как для штатного механизма PHP потребуется проксировать тело POST запроса целиком на backend со всеми вытекающими от сюда последствиями и ограничениями.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Именно такого объяснения я ожидал.